# Having a ticket on a train that doesn't stop at your destination?

Tags: trains, italy, night-transport, trenitalia

I have a fully bought ticket for an Italian IntercityNotte from Rome to Palermo (Sicily) in August, bought directly from Trenitalia

However, after looking at the official channel of information [Viaggiatreno](http://www.viaggiatreno.it/infomobilita/index.jsp) and the Trenitlia app, it appears that my train is either not the right one (the app states that my ICN is going to Siracuse and not Palermo) or times are all wrong (the website states that my ICN is supposed to depart and arrive 2h after the original train booked time)

These are the info on my tickets :

- ICN 1975
- 03/08/2022
- Rome Termini (20:31) - Palermo Centrale (09:24)

However :

- Both the app and the site (when looking by train number) states that `ICN1975` is scheduled to depart as usual but then the destination is advertised as Siracusa with no stops in Palermo
- The site, when making a `plan a journey` query with the appropriate details, states that the same train number is scheduled to depart Rome at `22:31` with an arrival at Palermo 2h later than booked at `11:24`

The RFI [Timetable](https://prm.rfi.it/qo_prm/QO_Pdf.aspx?Tipo=P&lin=it&id=2247) PDF for Roma Termini states, on page `102` that my train is scheduled to run as expected.

Since the call center number is tolled, I am not keen on calling them.

Is there a way, short of calling them, to validate that my train will leave as expected?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After finding the aforementioned RFI Timetable, I can comfortably put that fear of not getting that train to programmed mishaps and be assured that my train is scheduled as bought.

Indeed, on summer periods, `ICN1975` does go from Roma Termini onto Siracusa departing at 20:13.
But at Messina Centrale, the train split up between the continuing `ICN1975` and the *new* `ICN1957` that continues to Palermo. No changes necessary

What caused the confusion, is that that train *change* is nowhere to be seen on Trenitalia's website, from a booking perspective I would only ride on `1975`, which ends at Siracusa, and not on `1957`. And that the `22:13` given by ViaggiaTreno doesn't exist in official timetable

---

**Update :**

Done that trip and the train got to Palermo as expected on time

Comment: Just make sure you get on the right part of the train!

Comment: @WeatherVane Most night trains require reservations, and many night trains check tickets at the door, which makes getting on the wrong part difficult.

Comment: @gerrit Actually, you can mess that up, and the Italian railways thought about it. These ICNs are trains that goes on a ferry to cross the strait, and there are the deck of the ship that are accessible. People often climb in the wrong split of the train after going on the ferry deck, thankfully Trenitalia actually made the last stop before the split longer to allow for the few passengers to reach the correct carriages (the trains are split directly on the ferry due to how loading works)

Comment: I couldn't find a hint for this change / split on trenitalia.it either. Funny enough, the German bahn.de (who are not involved at all) gives the full details about split and name change: "Kurswagen [...] Verkehrt als ICN 1975 bis Messina Centrale, danach als ICN 1957"  (Cars with different destinations, changes from 1975 to 1957 at Messina Centrale)